# Radius of Convergence of Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of the series
$$
1+2x+\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{4^3x^3}{3!}+\ldots
$$
I found the general term $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}x^{n})$, and I know that the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{e},$ but I haven't been able to show this. I've tried to use the ratio test, but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: Use Hadamand's test for power series.  aka root test.  And stirling's approximation.

Comment: Could you expound a bit, I'm not familiar with that test? Also, is that from complex analysis? I would like to use a result from real analysis.

Comment: The [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Application_to_power_series) provides the radius of convergence for power series.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the ratio test:
$$ \frac{\frac{(n-1+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}{\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$
and
$$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$$

Answer (score 1):

The root test does it easily using $n! =(n/e)^nf(n)$ where $f(n) < n$.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's approximation:

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

root test:

$$\text{Radius of convergence}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\right|}\right)^{-1}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n+1)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n}}\right)^{-1}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[2n]{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)}\right)^{-1}$$

$$=e^{-1}$$